# Search a series of date time entries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a weird problem I'm trying to solve.

In my model I have a `start_time` and and `end_time`, we will refer to the model as “cost”. It's associated with an item.

The item will change price throughout the day, so on Monday from 5am to 1pm, it's one price, from 1pm to 5pm it's another price. It's then unavailable between 5pm and 6pm, and a 3rd price between 7pm and 2am the next day.

Representing this data is not that difficult, I have a table that contains cost and start/end times.

The problem is I have a set number of items, and a variable cost for time.

I can search and check to ensure I have the item available during a single time slot, and ensure it's actually “rentable” during that time.

How do I handle queries like (4pm - 7pm, which would fail, or 6am - 3pm, which would pass), across multiple rows, to ensure it's available for a continuous time interval?

How would you handle checking across the rows in a table and ensure they are continuous? Does this type of problem have a name?

Comment: Hi, it would be easier to answer your question if you include the actual table definitions and a complete example query, even if it is English not SQL.

Comment: Create rows of one hour or half hour and then check whether the item is available for rent by checking availability i the corresponding rows. You can have a look at activity selection   problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use range types for that.

As an example, I'll assume that your table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE item_data (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   start_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
   end_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
   available boolean NOT NULL,
   price NUMERIC(10,2)
);
```

You could then query for the availability of item 1 in between 6 am and 3 pm like this:

```
WITH q(i) AS
   (SELECT tstzrange '[2016-12-06 06:00:00, 2016-12-06 15:00:00)')
SELECT
   COALESCE(
      /*
       * Calculate the sum of the lengths of the intersection
       * between the time intervals and our given interval.
       */
      sum(
         upper(tstzrange(start_time, end_time, '[)') * q.i)
         - lower(tstzrange(start_time, end_time, '[)') * q.i)
      ),
      interval '0 hours'
   )
   /*
    * The item is available all the time if the above sum
    * is equal to the length of the given interval.
    */
   = upper(q.i) - lower(q.i)
FROM item_data, q
WHERE item_data.id = 1
   /* only consider times where the item is available */
   AND item_data.available
   /* only consider times that overlap with our given interval */
   AND tstzrange(item_data.start_time, item_data.end_time, '[)') && q.i
GROUP BY q.i;
```

This will return `TRUE` if item 1 is available all the time and `FALSE` if not.

The query assumes that the data are consistent, i.e. there is not more than one current state for a given item at a given time.

Other queries, like checking the data for consistency, could be handled similarly.

The query would be simpler if you chose to represent the interval as one value of type `tstzrange` instead of two timestamps. I would recommend that you do that.

Comment: For anyone who sees this later, I have created an SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/442b0/2 that demonstrates Laurenz's answer. It works for Postgresql. I added wday, to separate by days of the week. I'm working on seeing what I can do for SQLite.